# Designing a minor circuit

Tags: input, boolean

I've got this assignment that demands designing a minor circuit of 3 inputs so that the circuit returns the value of the less seen input.I've tried numerous times,but it seems like I'm stuck. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Better to ask on http://electronics.stackexchange.com I would suggest. And you could start by drawing up a truth table of the three inputs, and the expected/ desired output.

Comment: This is exactly how it sounds like.I'm sorry if i couldn't be more precise.

Comment: Electronics-related, move to Electronics SO site.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasW. Already did the truth table ,but I struggle to find a formula that binds everything together.

Answer (score 0):

You should drawing up a truth table of the three inputs, and the expected/ desired output.

To get the correct result, probably you could use an ADDER (or perhaps 2). You could sum A, B and C inputs. If more than 2 inputs are true, the "least seen" will be false. If less than 2 inputs are true, the "least seen" will be true.

Look up what gates are needed to implement an ADDER (possibly with carry) and then test its output.

The optimized solution might be simpler than this, but that shoudl give you some ideas.

Comment: Managed to finish it after looking up at some adder examples. I needed 2 XORs to make it work.Thanks for the advice

Comment: @AlexBalauca if my answer's correct, you should tick it as "accepted" or upvote it. Thanks!